# send multi ajax requests every 1 second

Tags: ajax, jquery, httprequest

i' tring to make chat like facebook chat :)

i'm using this requests like

Here To Get Room Users And roomBody

```
$('.room_users,.room_body').each(function () {
                 var page    = $(this).attr("page");
                 var room_id = $(this).parents('.room').children('.roomy_id').attr("value") ;
                 var url     = page+room_id ;
                 window.setInterval(function () { $(this).load(url);}, 200);
         });

Here To Get Room Lists

         $('#room_list').each(function () {
                 var page = $(this).attr("page");
                  var url = page ;
                  window.setInterval(function () {
                      $(this).load(url);
                  }, 60000);
         });
```

as you see my requests send every 1 second but not all requests return 202 status

many time it return 404 notfound

And Some time request send twice every 1 sec

[image: Here is pic of this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you server supports websockets or any form of Comet like long polling, try to utilize one.  In the mean time, add a timeout to your request AND only send the next ajax request AFTER the previous has returned or timed out...

```
function updaterooms() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: page,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    timeout:5000,
    success: function(data){
      // do what you need with the returned data...
      setTimeout('updaterooms()',1000);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
      $("#error").text("ERROR: " + textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
      setTimeout('updaterooms()',1000);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of spamming the server with requests every second you should look at [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).

It is a pattern that uses one long running request to stream data to the browser for a very long time in short intervals.