# How to properly use load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

In page I use jQuery `.load()` to apply database changes without reloading, have 2 steps:

1. load change.php?id=1&change=delete
2. reload list of items

Its simply illustration, I have more options (change rank, change text...), but all is implemented identically.

Problem: someone script doesn't show list, if I have in list.php console.log('text'), text shows in console, but list of items are not in div.

It happens more when I have 1+ requests per second.

It is possible to reach absolute reliability?

Thank you, Rob.

PS. I use simply onclick=func() in button and the

```
function func(){ 
$('#div1').load('change.php?id=1&change=delete'); 
$('#div2').load('list.php'); 
}
```

Comment: probably duplicate of [How to send Ajax request on every 1s using JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310118/how-to-send-ajax-request-on-every-1s-using-jquery) & [send multi ajax requests every 1 second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316690/send-multi-ajax-requests-every-1-second)

Answer (score 0):

did you check the response you get from the server?
If not try this snippet

```
$( "#success" ).load( "/not-here.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
```

Comment: status is always "success"

Comment: and whats in response? if theres nothing the error is most likely in the server method providing the data.

Comment: In response is output of list.php - its OK but response dont show in div.. I do not understand this.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution.

- Problem: delay in db update
- Solution:

  function func(){
  $('#div1').load('change.php?id=1&change=delete', function (){

  $('#div2').load('list.php');
  });

It is good solution?